# Anyone know of a Silverlight / Windows Phone 7 control that displays fractions?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I'm looking for a Silverlight / Windows Phone 7 control that displays fractions. Not something that gives "3/4" but something "prettier". Like below.

[image]

Thanks
PS. I'm looking to have each number added with a KeyDown event. Similar to the way a calculator would work. So I would need a "dynamic" type of placement of the numbers as opposed to placing them at specific coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for so I went with using 2 different font sizes to distinguish the whole number from the fraction. I got my idea from the following link.

http://www.xtremevbtalk.com/archive/index.php/t-320316.html

Answer (score 1):

I think it'd be fairly simple to create your own with the power of WPF. Here are a couple [examples](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/80520.aspx/1)

Hope it helps!

Edit:

There's a WPF version of the NumericUpDown control in Kevin Moore's [Bag-O-Tricks](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot) project. I think you may be able to get it to do what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I added a "PS" to my original post that I hope better explains what I need.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. But a NumericUpDown isn't what I'm looking for. Nor does it look like something I can modify to suit my needs. But thanks for your response.